# Есть ли в vc++2015 инструмент редактор ресурсов и редактор форм

Tags: vc++2015

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли в vc++2015 инструмент редактор ресурсов или редактор форм похожий как в данном редакторе ресурсов(ResourceHacker), что бы можно было увидеть все ли строки уменьшаются в форму, и как можно вызвать этот инструмент.
Это взято из готовых исходников с github.com https://github.com/ffes/nppsnippets/releases/tag/v1.4.0 это плагин Snippets для Notepad++, просто я переводил его на русский язык из исходников. А то мне после сборки библиотеки этого плагина в vc++2015 еще приходиться повторно редактировать в ResourceHacker потому что некоторые слова длиннее и они в форме получаются обрезанные.

При попытке открытия файла ресурса в vc++2015 или vc++2017 выходит ошибка, я показал это автору плагина. Но автор плагина не может найти и исправить эту ошибку.
https://github.com/ffes/nppsnippets/issues/23

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странный какой-то вопрос... а как по-вашему в Visual Studio программы пишут, без ресурсов? Есть там все, что нужно для работы.

Comment: Сейчас я первый раз в жизни начал пользоваться Visual Studio лишь для того что бы попробовать перевести плагин на русский язык. И для этого задаю здесь свой вопрос, надеясь на помощь опытных в этом деле людей.

Comment: Есть и он открыт у вас на скриншоте

Comment: Может я и не понятно выражаюсь, но мне нужно вызвать само окно с формой как показано на фото с ResourceHacker, а в Visual Studio на данный момент  я вижу только сроки кода этого окна.

Comment: Нету. Именно ResourceHacker все для этого используют.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, получается пока не скомпилируешь файл  то не возможно удивить это окно?

Comment: Откройте панель ресурсов `View / Resource View' и там два раза щелкните на нужном диалоге. Не нужны никакие ресурс хакеры, в студии есть абсолютно все что надо для разработки.

Comment: freim  ...если я правильно вас понял то выскакивает ошибка https://i.imgur.com/8OLdDVx.png

Comment: freim ...ради интереса скачал исходники от Notepad++ и все диалоговые окна\формы прекрасно отображаются вот фото https://i.imgur.com/Ekj0H8o.png Одно не пойму почему при просмотре ресурсов плагина этого нет и выскакивает ошибка.

Comment: В Студии не было и нет просмотрщиков дизайна _окон_ (_форм_). _Диалоговые_ окна - есть.

Comment: Alexander Petrov ...вы смотрели фото которые я добавил в комментария?

Comment: Там _диалоги_ - _диалоговые_ окна. Не _основное_ окно.

Comment: Так в плагине и есть только диалоговые окна, но они не открываются и выдают ошибку. Фото это ошибки есть в комментариях.